# how to open device language settings programmatically in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

```
public void onClick(View v) {

 final Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

final ComponentName cn= new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS");

intent.setComponent(cn);

intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, When the user hits the back button, it will return to your app.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

It will bring you to the system language menu. Or:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS), 0);
```

For keyboards and inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // button 2 was clicked!

 startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
   }
  });
```

This tutorial can be helpful

http://weimenglee.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-tip-programmatically-displaying.html

If you want to use other constants instead of `ACTION_SETTINGS` then take a look of android official documentations .http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html